# function that calls the next element in a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to understand how Javascript and HTML5 work. I have a nav and when you press Part One I'm trying to show Content 1, when you press Part Two..etc. I have tried a couple things, and I am clearly not understand the .next properly, but I can only get it to show the first element, but when I press Part Two, Content Two doesn't show. I guess I am visualizing it wrong, instead of .first(), .next made sense to me since I feel like that would just get the next element. Anyways, here's some code, thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Assignment 6 | jQuery Usability </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">


<!-- This matches the CSS width to the device width, and prevents forced overview without disabling zooming -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<!-- Helpful for older Blackberries -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<!-- Helpful for older IE mobile -->
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<!-- Apple iOS-specific --> 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">


<!-- enforce CSS3 media queries in IE 8 and older -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Note: this won't work when testing locally; you'll need to upload your files to a server to test it in IE -->


<!-- HTML5shiv, for IE 6, 7 and 8 -->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul').hide();

    $('a.btnDown').click(function() {

        $('nav>ul').fadeIn(200);

    }); //closes a.btnDown

    $('a.contentDown').click(function() {
        $('body>aside>ul').first().fadeIn(200);

    }); //closes contentDown





}); //closes .ready()
</script>

</head>

<body>

<nav>
    <h1><a class="btnDown" href="#"> Main Menu </a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Part One </a></li>

            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Part Two </a></li>

            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Part Three </a></li>

            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Student Notes 1 </a></li>

            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Student Notes 2 </a></li>

            <li><a class="contentDown" href="#"> Student Notes 3</a></li>

        </ul>

</nav>

<aside>

                <ul>
                    <li> Content 1 </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li> Content 2 </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li> Content 3 </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li> Content 4 </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li> Content 5 </li>
                </ul>


                <ul>
                    <li> Content 6 </li>
                </ul>
</aside>

<figure>

<!-- PUT TV IMAGE HERE -->
</figure>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given markup, the easiest solution is to work with the index of the elements as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('ul').hide();

    $('a.btnDown').click(function () {
        $('nav>ul').fadeIn(200);
        return false;
    }); //closes a.btnDown

    //all the content elements
    var $suls = $('body>aside>ul');
    var $as = $('a.contentDown').click(function () {
        //hide visible content item
        $suls.filter(':visible').hide();
        //display the content item in the same position as the clicked contentDown
        $suls.eq($as.index(this)).fadeIn(200);
    }); //closes contentDown
}); //closes .ready()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Tmaz/)

Comment: very interesting! I def have not learn some of these things, but this makes sense to me since I do have a programming background. I'll checkout "fitler() and eq()" thank you sir.

Comment: Although I do have a question, you obviously know what you're doing. I don't want to produce bad code and I did notice you say "with the given markup" am I doing something against what I should be doing as a web developer? I do like your solution, but I would def change my code if I knew that this was the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @user3380292 there is nothing king of bad in this setup... if you can make sure the order of elements in `nav` and `aside` will always be same

Comment: @user3380292 another solution will be is to make the relation more explicit by using id or some other selectors so you can place the contents in any order.... it is more of which way you prefer

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('ul').hide();
$('a.btnDown').click(function () {
    $('nav>ul').fadeIn(200);
}); 
$('a.contentDown').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index('.contentDown');
    $('body>aside>ul:eq(' + idx + ')').fadeIn(200).siblings('ul').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yCHGL/)**